# Preg Match All Text not matching past the initial line

Tags: php, preg-match-all

So I am working on a PHP application where a user would be able to store text using a keyword i.e. Keyword "Br" text "Back bone polished". For this particular section the user would be able to edit all of the text they have stored in the database. The information would be presented inside of a standard text area as follows:

Text Area

```
<textarea rows="15" cols="20" id="inputMulti" wrap="hard" name="inputMulti">
```

Actual Text inside text area

```
na  "No acute cardiopulmonary abnormality. "

!   "Test Bed - Chrome on MacBook Pro.

1. Font is not Courier.
2. Compiler is not working.
3. Buttons are not high-lighting.
4. Edit and Delete buttons not working in Reports.
5. multiple codes "entered" are inappropriately separated by commas, that are carried over from box 1. 
6. On Show list page, instead of view, we can just simplify and go straight to edit.
7. Once you Delete a code from the Code View page, you get an Page Not Found error.
8. MRI Code Typer is not linked to Home; and actually, Home doesn't need to be there, the MRI Code Typer 2 would be fine.
9. Box 2 doesn't lengthen as expected; once text field is expanded, "only" a part of it is seen, until additional typing is performed, only then does Box 2 expand properly."

0c  "Comparison: unavailable . 

FINDINGS:

$$$L,PL,H,B,f0$

IMPRESSION:
$na$
$$"

L   """""There is no discernible mass or lobar pneumonia. "

f0  "No displaced fracture or acute osseous deformity is seen. "
```

The key is before the \t" and the text for the respective key is inside the respective "".

Now what I am trying to do is pull everything in between the respective "". The delima is that I cannot explode by " because the text inside the "" may contain " which would of course cause issues.

I have managed to create a preg_match_all expression as follows.

```
preg_match_all("/[\t][\"^\a](...*)[\"$\z\n\r]/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Output from Preg Match All

```
array(
0=> "No acute cardiopulmonary abnormality. "
1=> "Test Bed - Chrome on MacBook Pro.
2=> "Comparison: unavailable . 
3=> """""There is no discernible mass or lobar pneumonia. "
4=> "No displaced fracture or acute osseous deformity is seen. "
)
```

Now this partially works as it grabs the correct text for each line, but if you notice at key 2 it doesn't include all the text in between the "" as it stops after the initial match although it should continue until it reaches the end of the match which expands over several lines.

I have tried to add the s modifier but that only puts all the matches inside one array that isn't broken up by lines. I also tried the m modifier and that doesn't seem to change anything at all.

Comment: So to get this straight in my head, the 2 => Comparison... should extend all the way until it hits the L prefixing index 3?

Comment: The 2=> Should Include everything up until "Comparison: unavailable . FINDINGS:

$$$L,PL,H,B,f0$

IMPRESSION:
$na$
$$"

Comment: Could you confirm that literal quotes (inside quoted parts) are escaped with an other quote (like `"""""There is no discernible mass or lobar pneumonia. "` that gives `"" There is no discernible mass or lobar pneumonia. `)?

Comment: The main problem is that your format is inconsistent, there is no rule to know what is the closing quote.

Comment: This is why I come to you guys for help. I am not sure what you mean by your earlier comment, but I think that only shows when I use the "U" modifier.

Comment: What @CasimiretHippolyte means is altough you enclose the text in double quotes, you have them in the middle of the text as well (examples: "entered", "only", """" after the L keyword) which makes difficult to find an appropriate rule to match what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several tests I think I got it. Try this pattern:

```
preg_match_all("/\t\"([^\t]*)\"/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

The pattern is made to match everything except a tab (which is the separator between the keyword and the text). This will include the newlines in the match, in the case of multiline text. For this I'm considering the text won't have tabs in the middle, i.e. the tabs are only used to separate the keyword from its corresponding text.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just beating my head against the wall. I'll disable the ability to use the tab key to be safe, but thanks again.

Comment: Just deleted the previous comment it was my error, thanks again.